# Mapping Table with additional fields codefirst

Tags: c#, migration, code-first

I`m using code first and I have this mapping table

```
 public class OpirtiunitiesSourcerUsers
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("SourcedUser")]
        public int SourcedUserID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("SourcedPartner")]
        public int SourcedPartnerID { get; set; }

        public virtual SourcedUser SourcedUser { get; set; }
        public virtual SourcedPartner SourcedPartner { get; set; }

        public string ApproversRole { get; set; }
    }
```

when I try to add new OpirtiunitiesSourcerUsers exception was thrown 
**An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**

```
OpirtiunitiesSourcerUsers opp1 = new OpirtiunitiesSourcerUsers()
                                {
                                    SourcedUser = someUser,
                                    ApproversRole = "someRole",
                                    SourcedPartner = somePartner
                                };
                                context.OpirtiunitiesSourcerUsers.Add(opp1);
```